# Find a regular expression to get substrings with file extensions

Tags: c#, string, split

There are several variants of the strings:

1. `` "txt files `(*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*`" ``
2. `` "Image Files`|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;`" ``
3. `` "Excel Files `(*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv`" ``

The substring can end with any character `(space, ',', '.', '|', ';') -` it doesn't matter.

Tried the following options: "`[^*].{3,4}(.?);", "[^*]+.(.?);`".

**I need a regular expression to get `string[] = {.jpg, .jpeg, ...}`**, preferably without duplicate elements.

Comment: i'd rather use string split.

Comment: Those pipe-separated strings look like Win32 file dialog filters. The wildcard logic employed there is... awkward, because in Win32 dialogs the wildcard filter `*.*` will match filenames that lack an extension, but when treated as a string-matching wildcard it won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you *really* need a regular expression?

First off, if you split by `|`, each odd entry in the result is a list of extensions. You can then split that *again* by `;` to get the extensions, which you can then flatten into a single sequence and trim each element of the starting `*`. Finally, get the distinct set of that and put that into an array.

This can all be accomplished with `Split` and Linq:

```
var extensions = filter.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Where((x, i) => i % 2 != 0)
                       .SelectMany(x => x.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                       .Select(x => x.TrimStart('*'))
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToArray();
```

Removing empty entries from the split ensures that if you end with a separator it just gets ignored.

See it in action on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D8eYlG).

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Split

I think I too would do it with `Split` and it should be possible to do it like:

```
str.Split('*',';','|')
  .Where(s => s.StartsWith(".") && s[1..].All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit))
  .Distinct();
```

Note:
This doesn't make any insistence about the length of the extension. You can add something into the Where for these cases if you want, e.g.:

```
&& s.Length is >3 and <6
```

.. a 3 or 4 length extension is between 4 and 5 long with the dot and this is where the "greater than 3 and less than 6" comes from. Note that it uses pattern matching which is a recent c# addition. If your c# is older you'll need some older style of length checking..

---

#### Regex

..but as a Regex learning opportunity for you, extracting the file extensions from the string is easier with a capturing group:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\*(?<x>\.\w{3,4})\b");
var arr = r.Matches()
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups["x"].Value)
  .Distinct();
```

The Regex itself looks for a literal `*` then starts capturing characters into a group named x with `(?<x>`. Captured characters are: a literal dot, followed by between 3 and 4 word characters (a-z, 0-9). I chose between 3 and 4 because your code chose that but note extensions can be less or more so you may tweak that. The final bit of the Regex demands a word boundary `\b` after 3 or 4 chars because we don't want partial matches of extensions longer than 4 chars. A word boundary means the extension has finish (the next char is a non word char) after 3 or 4 chars

To extract that data from this using LINQ we have to do something like `Cast` the resulting collection entries to a Match; they're Matches already but a MatchCollection doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` because it's old, so it's not LINQ compatible unless we do something like Cast to make it so.

The `Select` retrieves the string value from the capture group, which is the `.xxx` extension and `Distinct` removes duplicates

---

#### Your Regex

As to why your tries didn't work:

```
[^*]
    .{3,4}
          (.?)
              ;
```

This matches

- char that is any char except asterisk,
- followed by 3 or 4 of any char,
- followed by zero or one of any char, that is captured into an unnamed group,
- followed by semicolon".

It could perhaps be adjusted to work in some cases but it doesn't seem to specify the pattern of chars you're looking for

```
[^*]+
     .  
      (.?)
          ;
```

This matches

- one or more of char that is any char except asterisk,
- followed by any char,
- followed by zero or one of any char that is captured into an unnamed group,
- followed by semicolon"

I suspect you're thinking that `^` is an escape that allows to match literal `*` - escape is `\`,

When `^` used as the first char inside `[ ]` it means "all chars except" so where I suspect you were trying to match a literal asterisk you actually ended up matching the exact opposite

Actually most chars lose their special meaning when placed inside a character class so `[*]` would be "match literal asterisk" just like `\*` is

Comment: Your regular expression example works fine, but the Linq example fails.

Comment: @Tatami What error do you get? It seems to work for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dGd6KU

Comment: When we use the example marked as an answer, the result will be a set of extensions without extra punctuation. It is also not necessary to specify a set of characters to hide during sampling. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/RZU6nW

Answer (score 1):

Your example strings seem to consist of an optional leading part between parenthesis followed by a pipe `|` and then the extensions.

If you want to match the format of the data, you can use a capture group with the same name,  and the [Group.Captures Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-6.0).

```
\b[fF]iles\b[^*()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?\|\*(?<ext>\.[\w*]+)(?:[,;]\*(?<ext>\.[\w*]+))*
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\b[fF]iles\b` Match either files or Files
- `[^*()]*` Optionally match any char except `*` `(` `)`
- `(?:\([^()]*\))?` Optionally match a part between parenthesis
- `\|\*` Match `|*`
- `(?<ext>\.[\w*]+)` Named group *ext*, match `.` and 1+ times a word char or `*`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[,;]\*` Match either `,` or `;` followed by `*`
  - `(?<ext>\.[\w*]+)` Same pattern for group *ext*
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to get all the extensions

See a [C# regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCfXMp/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/kpGa6v).

For example

```
string pattern = @"\b[fF]iles\b[^*()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?\|\*(?<ext>\.[\w*]+)(?:[,;]\*(?<ext>\.[\w*]+))*";    
string input = @"txt files `(*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*`
Image Files`|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;`
Excel Files `(*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv`";

var strings = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)

.SelectMany(m => m.Groups["ext"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value))
.ToArray()
.Distinct();

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output

```
.txt
.*
.jpg
.jpeg
.png
.xls
.xlsx
.csv
```

---

Another shorter pattern not related to the data format, matching a dot and either 3 or 4 word characters or an asterix and asserting a dot to the left:

```
 (?<=\*)\.(?:\w{3,4}\b|\*)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EoIkD9/1).